# What is the best way to send email to non-verified email address using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have written a script in AWS lambda to send email to each IAM user whose access key is older than 90 days. This code is working fine with verified email `From` and `To` in AWS SES in one AWS account.

Now I am planning to implement it without verifying `To` email addresses and also want to implement in multiple AWS accounts.

I have gone through some AWS SES documents but it is not still clear to me. I found following two options:
Here, I have added my doubts with options

**Option 1:** I can request AWS support team to remove sandbox mode.
**Questions :**  I have seven AWS accounts. Do I need to raise a request in each AWS account to remove sandbox mode? What are the disadvantage of removing `sandbox` mode?

**Option 2:** The other options is, I can verify domain name.

**Questions:**  I want to use same domain (example.com)in multiple AWS accounts.
Is it possible to verify same domain in multiple AWS account? or Can we verify in one account and use it in multiple accounts?

Answer (score 1):

There is a procedure in this topic that describes how to move out of sandbox mode and have no restrictions on your SES functionality. This is the route to follow:

[Moving out of the Amazon SES sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)